# Why does the performance of a hard drive with ext4 vary over time?

Tags: hard-drive, performance, ext4, benchmarking

I have a strange problem with a Western Digital HDD.

The performance of this drive varies pretty significantly over time. The observed range goes from ~50MB/s to more than 100 MB/s. The performance is more or less stable for several minutes (or even hours), but then suddenly drops/increases.
Performance is using `dd`, repeatedly writing relatively a large file (50 MB to 10 GB) to an `ext4` file system on the HDD (and overwriting it subsequently by the next run of the performance test).
This can be better visualized in a figure.

[image: Plot of throughput over time]

I do expect some variation, and I also expect that performance somehow might depend on the file size (which it apparently does, as the linked image shows). But I'm quite surprised by these jumps in performance.

**My question(s):**

- Is this something that could be caused by the operating system/file system?
- Is this rather something on the hardware layer, something in the controller of the HDD that's behaving strangely?
- May this have something to do with the arrangement of blocks/sectors on the disk?

**Environment details:**

- Intel Core i5-8365UE
- Ubuntu 22.04
- 1TB HDD formatted with `ext4` (default settings, only one partition for whole drive), HDD Model: `WDC WD10JUCT-63CYNY0`
- Partition has 75% free space, so there should be plenty of space to avoid file fragmentation
- Command for testing throughput `dd bs=1MB count=$cnt if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/file/on/ext4partition conv=fdatasync`, `$cnt` varies from 50 to 10000. I used large sizes to ensure that disk caches do not play a big role. `conv=fdatasync`, as far as I understand, ensures that everything is synced to disk, so OS caches should not have a big impact either.
- During the experiment, there is no other process writing to or reading from this drive (the system partition is on a separate device (SSD)).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is a single answer, but I expect a few things are going on.

- On a hard drive the outer tracks are about twice the speed of the inner ones.
- File fragmentation means that writes may be scattered on the drive.
- OS and disk caching might play a small roll.
- Other disk activity could significantly impact speed.  (Not only are hdds slower then SSD's speedwise, the IOPs (analogous to ping) are very high compared to SSD's so scattered reads and/or writes can disproportionately slow writes down.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question: `dd` is the only process that is writing during the experiment, and I assumed that fragmentation is not an issue for a partition with 750GB of free space. I also tried to avoid OS caching have an impact on the result (`conv=fdatasync`).